# Use boosting for decision trees and importance of concept hierarchies

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, decision-tree, ensemble-learning

I have two questions.
1. To improve the performance of classifiers, most of the times we use bagging or boosting methods.Can we use boosting to improve the accuracy of decision tree classifier?
2. We calculate concept hierarchies for certain attributes. What is the purpose of calculating them before data mining. Are there any semi-supervised method existing to obtain it when meta data is not available?

Answer (score 3):

> Can we use boosting to improve the accuracy of decision tree classifier?

I assume the decision tree you said is a "deep" decision tree. In my experience, boosting can be used as an ensemble method to combine deep decision trees. However, the performance gain is very limited. Boosting is more applicable to "weak" classifiers, e.g., very shallow decision trees or "decision [stumps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_stump)" (depth 1 decision tree).

Below is a figure I copied from [ESL](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/local.ftp/Springer/OLD/ESLII_print4.pdf) - Elements of Statistical Learning -Chapter10. In this graph, we vary the size of the tree (from 1 node to 100 nodes) (the weak classifier), and we plot the test-error against the boosting iterations. You will see that the stumps perform the best. The intuition behind this is, more nodes in the tree introduce higher level of interactions between variables. When a decision stump is used, no interactions are permitted. When node number is 3, two-variable interaction effects are allowed, and so on. However, the generative function behind adaBoost is additive, so boosting models with node number > 2 incurs unnecessary variance and hence the higher test error. The author suggested to keep node number <= 6.

[image]

> We calculate concept hierarchies for certain attributes. What is the
>   purpose of calculating them before data mining.

One of the motivation for data clustering could be **scalability**. Let's use SVM classifier as an example. The training time of the standard SVM is `O(n^3)`. Thus it is not scalable for very large datasets. One idea to approach this issue is to add a preprocessing step: **clustering feature**, so that the centroid of each cluster becomes the representative feature of the entire cluster. See below graph. Each circle represents a cluster. Now the centroid of each cluster is used as features to do SVM training. This greatly reduced the instance space. Suppose you have now `m` clusters. Then the training time is `O(m^3)`. Since `m << n`, problem solved. See [here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~lifeifei/cs6931/SVM.pdf) for details of this hierarchical clustering SVM. 
[image]

> Are there any semi-supervised method existing to obtain it when meta data is not
>   available?

See [Agglomerative Clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) for an unsupervised method.
Also there is supervised method, which is often used to learn a hierarchy over the feature space. The state-of-the-art are:

- Label Partitioning for sublinear ranking (from [google](http://www.thespermwhale.com/jaseweston/papers/label_partitioner.pdf))
- fastXML (from [microsoft research](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/manik/pubs/prabhu14.pdf))

I never used any semi-supervised hierarchical clustering algorithm, but here is [one](http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~taoli/pub/semi-supervised-2011.pdf) I found via google search.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77018/random-forest-is-it-a-boosting-algorithm), [Random Forest models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) are a bagged extension of decision trees.

Since boosting algorithms seek to clamp correct predictions and provide only incorrectly classified observations to subsequent training rounds, it will lead to quite severe overfitting during the later training stages, because the trees are presented with limited samples and are not well-suited for that kind of prediction.

Contrast this with bagging where the subset used for subsequent rounds of training is randomly chosen, rather than being chosen as the incorrectly labeled samples. This means that each weak classifier in the bagging steps has a reasonable chance to discern structure in the data, and is not being clamped to an artificially small subset. For a decision tree, this is quite important. Qualitatively this is one reason why bagging (random forests) is common with decision trees, while boosting is less common.

Lastly, there was recent controversial research about the accuracy of boosting in the face of classification noise (errors in the training labels): ["Random Classification Noise Defeats All Convex Potential Boosters"](http://www.phillong.info/publications/LS09_potential.pdf). The conclusion is that for a given boosting algorithm (from a special family of such algorithms), base classifier type, and noise rate, you can construct a data set tailored to the situation which is efficient to learn if the noise rate is zero, but which cannot be learned with an ultimate (post-boosting) prediction accuracy better than 1/2 in the presence of any non-zero noise rate.  The extent to which this is intended to dissuade practitioners from using the convex boosters is still debated, and there are other classes of boosters which don't suffer the same limitation, but are much less common and less widely available in open source learning libraries.